# How to get multiple slices of the same size from a `Tensor`?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `I` of indices (of unknown shape `n`), that indicates where slices each of constant length `slice_length` should start from a tensor `T` (of shape `t_length`).

What I want to get is a tensor of shape `(n, slice_length)`, consisting of slices of `T`.

For example, if `T` is `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `I` is `[1,3,1]`, and `slice_length` is `2`, the resulting tensor should be

```
[[1,2],
 [3,4],
 [1,2]]
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: So, based on the indices (`I`), you need to slice (with length `2`) the tensor of `T`? If so, then how the 2 indices need to be picked from `I` to get the param of `T`, is it randomly?

Comment: @M.Innat `I` contains starting indices of each slice. E.g. `[1,3,1]` means I need 3 slices of T starting at indices 1, 3, 1. E.g. `tf.stack([ T[I[0]..I[0]+2], T[I[1]..I[1]+2], ...])`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing. Not sure if there is a better way.

```py
slice_base_indices = tf.range(0, slice_length)
slice_base_indices = tf.expand_dims(slice_base_indices, axis=1)
indices = slice_base_indices + I
indices = tf.transpose(indices)
return tf.gather(T, indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I understand that you need to first build your indices based on what you need, and the rest of the stuff is pretty simple. Here is one way to achieve what you mention in the comment box.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

T = tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
x = tf.constant([1,3,1])
y = x + 1
I = tf.stack([x, y], -1)

tf.gather(T, I)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)>
```